# C# Adding arguments to a 3rd party delegate signature

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a 3rd party delegate with a "void Method (string)" signature.
The problem is I want/need to pass extra additional information to MySubscribedMethod (Lets say MyIntArg for simplicity).  I know this information at the time of the subscription, but I obviously not allowed to alter the MySubscribedMethod parameter list.

```
ThirdPartyClass.ThirdPartyDelagate += MySubscribedMethod; // Want to provide MyIntArg
public void MySubscribedMethod(string Arg) {} // Would like to receive MyIntArg
```

Does anyone know an elegant work around for this type of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what closures were designed for:

```
int myIntArg = whatever;
ThirdPartyClass.ThirdPartyDelagate += s => MySubscribedMethod(s, myIntArg);

public void MySubscribedMethod(string Arg, int intArg) {}
```

The C# compiler will magically create all the necessary infrastructure for you to ensure that `myIntArg` is passed into `MySubscribedMethod` when `ThirdPartyDelegate` is invoked

(note there are various subtlies around what exact value gets passed in that only really matter if you're using this in a loop or changing `myIntArg` after you've assigned the delegate; see [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/jolson/archive/2008/06/13/lambdas---know-your-closures.aspx) if you're interested in the gory details)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  For anyone interested I found a good definition of closures at http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained

Comment: Just for closure (pun) is the value of myIntArg copied at the time of closure creation.  For example if myIntArg was a reference type that changed before the delegate was invoked would I receive the original or modified value?

Comment: The modified one. The value passed as the argument to `MySubscribedMethod` is the value of the variable _at that point_, not the 'original' value when the closure is created.